# How to use EncdDecd.EncodeStream

Tags: delphi, mime

I want to encode a stream but something doesn't work. After encoding the output stream is empty:

```
procedure TForm5.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
VAR s: String;
    InpStream, OutStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
 InpStream:= TMemoryStream.Create;
 OutStream:= TMemoryStream.Create;

 s:= 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz'+CRLF+'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz';
 InpStream.WriteBuffer(s[1], Length(s));                  <---- after this, Size of Inpstream is 34

 EncdDecd.EncodeStream(InpStream, OutStream);

 if OutStream.Size<= 0
 then EmptyDummy;              <------- OutStream.Size is zero!

 FreeAndNil(InpStream);
 FreeAndNil(OutStream);
end;
```

Comment: After writing to InpStream, seek to the beginning: `InpStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);`

Comment: Make sure you set your `InpStream` position to `0` before you call `EncodeStream`

Comment: What's wrong with EncodeStream? A function like this should act as a blackbox. I should not care from where (Position) it reads the data.

Comment: Welcome to the nature of streams :-)

Comment: Please post as answer so I can accept.

Comment: If streams did not work this way, how would you encode or decode the second half of a stream!

Comment: from the code - repeat BytesRead := Input.Read(InBuf, SizeOf(InBuf));.....So, it start from where you have set the position. And yes, the function should act like a blackbox...

Comment: @David, well, then how would you encode the first half of the stream with this function ? In my view it's a "bug" since who would ever want to pass a stream without telling how many bytes to process to a function which will process it from the current position till the end. That position reset would be more than welcomed there.